# Popcorn Time stopped working on Ubuntu

Tags: 14.04, windows, streaming

Before several weeks desktop software PopcornTime stop to work with API. Every time when I try to list a movies I got message (the link is down)

[image]

> "The remote movies API failed to respond, please chec
>   http://status.popcorntime.io and try again later."

But, today I found out that the PopcornTime actually works on friend's laptop, which is on Windows.

Anyone know what's going on and what's the solutions?

Comment: your friend might be using the other popcorn time fork, the one from popcorn-time.se. The one from popcorntime.io is **dead** as says http://status.popcorntime.io/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The popcorn time is alive at http://popcorntime.ag/ and finally version for Ubuntu works fine.

Answer (score 0):

The official popcorntime.io website was shot down by the MPAA. The backend (Yify Torrents) was also just shut down by the MPAA. You'll have to download from other sources for now.

Shame on you for illegally streaming pirated movies! (even though everyone does)

Comment: But uploading the movies from USA for you to stream is illegal. Nice blame shift! :-P